# Should I forgo Stories for a very short campaign?

Tags: 7th-sea-2e

I'm about to run a game of 7th Sea (second edition) to my friends. We've agreed to keep this game short, probably between three and five sessions.

The only person in the group with prior experience of 7th Sea has only played a single, similarly short game before. In this game, they did not use the Stories mechanic (p. 159 in my 7th Sea book, Step 7 of character creation). I can see how the mechanic could be problematic in very short games, as there's a chance the Stories remain unfinished and there's little time to use the rewards from a completed Story. However, first impressions are prone to being wrong.

Experienced players of 7th Sea, what are the pros and cons of using the Stories in a campaign of only five or less sessions? Should I forgo them or not?

Answer (score 3):

Pros to Stories:

- Everyone gets XP equally
- You know exactly when to expect advancement
- Advancement must be planned

Cons to Stories:

- Changing your mind
- Number of sessions does not fairly represent the level of challenge
- The story may have nothing to do with the plot at hand

In 1st edition, the GM gave XP based on the session, plot progression, and there were character "advantages" called Backstories.  Backstories were personal character arcs, and when you completed them you got a lump sum of XP based on the value of the backstory (which was supposed to directly relate to the complexity/danger of the problem).  They were things like Lost Relative, Rival, Treasure Map, Cursed, etc.  The idea was that with the reward at the end it would keep players on task and in character.

Both of these methods are still subject to the same pitfall: The stories rarely work together.  Even when players make their characters together, they tend not to combine their efforts for more than to get past the "tavern scene" during creation.  It can also serve to derail the plot at hand because characters want to go off and do their own thing.

If you are planning to make this a one-shot arc, you can include the stories if you help it keeps them on task within your plot, but otherwise in a time frame that short it serves to be a distraction.  I would recommend GM caveat - if you feel like they deserve something and it fits within the narrative, toss it their way. Either that, or don't do them and should the character make a return to another session of yours, work out their advancement for the new session.